# Проблема mstest: тестов не обнаружено

Tags: c#, wpf, mstest

Есть программа на c#. В ней есть фалы. Необходимо сделать тест на наличие файла

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

using System.IO;

namespace Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class tests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public bool TestMethod1()
        {
            try
            {
                var path = @"..\..\TabMAIN.xaml";
                var exist = File.Exists(path);
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вот то что получилось у меня. Программа выдаёт что тестов не обнаружено. Подскажите: что здесь не так?

Comment: А как вы запускаете тесты?

Comment: Файловая система - это такая вещь, которая относится к инфраструктуре, поэтому лучше использовать [System.IO.Abstractions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Abstractions) и мокать реальную файловую систему. Пример как - в этой статье есть: http://www.dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Unit-Testing-C-File-Access-Code-with-SystemIOAbstractions А не видит теста, потому что тест должен иметь на выходе тип void.

Comment: @AK формально автор может защититься и сказать, что тест приемочный, например :-)

Comment: @АртёмОконечников Я пишу комментарии для адекватных людей, которые могут подумать, взвесить риски и принять решение (даже и отказ от предложенной техники, почему бы и нет?), а не для тех, кто озабочен чтобы лучше выглядеть в чьих-то глазах и защищать своё эго от вариантов улучшения кода. Текущий тест, пусть даже сделанный и как приёмочный, очень хрупок. Обычно пути из теста не совпадают с путями из приложения (например, я в nUnit оперирую `TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory`) и можно легко ошибиться: тест будет зелёный, а в приложении ошибка. Вон, видели относительный путь к файлу?

Comment: @AK это была попытка пошутить :-) У вас по теме комментарий вполне. (Внешняя зависимость и для приемочного теста smell, как и try/catch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего потому, что тест не должен ничего возвращать. А падать он должен при помощи `Assert`.

Так как [`File.Exists`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=net-5.0) возвращает `false`, а не исключение, если файл не найден или нет полномочий его прочитать, то можно переписать тест без использования `try/catch`

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    // Given
    var path = @"..\..\TabMAIN.xaml";

    // When
    var actual = File.Exists(path);

    // Then
    Assert.IsTrue(actual, $"File {path} not found");
}
```

Comment: Не "скорее всего", а это "прям точнее некуда".

Comment: Только вот сам тест написан неправильно. [File.Exists](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_IO_File_Exists_System_String_) по документации не выкидывает никаких исключений, он просто тихо возвращает bool - поэтому тест всегда будет зелёный. Поэтому надо использовать Assert.IsTrue или что там в mstest для этого есть.

Comment: @AK мне поправить или автор пускай с этим разбирается?

Comment: Поправьте конечно.